# Journey Builder Salesforce Data Source Campaigns not showing all Campaigns in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, campaign, campaign-member

When I use Salesforce Data as an entry source in Marketing Cloud I'm not seeing all the Campaigns that are active on the CRM side. There are some that I am seeing but a vast majority are not showing up. I have the Campaign object synchronized and actively updating.

Do I also need to synchronize the campaign member object? Is there anything else I'm missing or need to update in order for the Campaigns to reflect the current active campaigns.

Comment: Synching data from Salesforce has got nothing to do with which campaigns you can use in JB. You need to check the permissions in Salesforce of the API user used for the connection between the Clouds. Can you log into Salesforce as the API user and verify which campaigns you see in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the solution which was actually straightforward. After logging in and making sure that the API user has visibility to all the campaigns the solution ended up that the Campaign has to be changed to Active status in the CRM before it will show up in Marketing Cloud Journey Builder Salesforce Entry data.